# Android how to create a new file for each download?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider

I am creating an app where every time press the download button it's create a pdf file in my storage.My problem is newly created file overwrites the existing file with same file name.I need to download with new filename.What i am trying

```
      dirpath = 
      android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      // int increase=0;
       file = new File(dirpath+"/NewPDF.pdf");
       if(file.exists()){
           increase++;
           file = new File(dirpath + "/NewPDF" +increase+".pdf");}
```

This above lines of program create  files but i need to open the last download file

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( file,"/NewPDF.pdf"));
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      startActivity(intent);
```

These above lines of code generate an error.

```
      Error:File no longer exist,the file maybe deleted or changed or 
     removed by another program
```

1.create a new file and prevent overwiting whenever i click the button
2.open the last downloaded file
I am new to Android and little confused about that and kindly need some help from you guys.

Comment: use `System.currentTimeMillis();` instead of `increase`.

Comment: Okay, Why do you want to download the file that has already been downloaded? I mean, It should not be the case.

Comment: @Wizard everytime i change the content and set the download..so already download files will be restricted.my problem is  all files are created with a same filename so it overwrites the existing file ,now i want  to set the  filename dynamically for each download.

Comment: @Karthi028 But, why don't you just delete the previous file and download the latest one. Downloading the new one each time without deleting the previous one - is the waste of storage. My approach - your server file will have some unique id, save your file with that id. By doing so.. it will be easy to track even if it is in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the same name to every file you create. Try giving a unique name like this:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
```

the `randomUUIDString` will be your unique string for the pdf files. Also, store these strings in a SQLite db if you wish to use them.

Comment: ..yeah sure! :)

Answer (score 1):

You call `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( file,"/NewPDF.pdf"));` for open file, so why you added **/NewPDF.pdf** because its already in your file. just remove it.

Replace this line

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( file,"/NewPDF.pdf"));
```

to

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( file));
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you have entered in intent not matching with the created file path.

Try this.

```
dirpath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String lastFilePath = null;
      // int increase=0;
       file = new File(dirpath+"/NewPDF.pdf");
       if(file.exists()){
           increase++;
           file = new File(dirpath + "/NewPDF" +increase+".pdf");}
           lastFilePath =  file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Then you can open the file like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(lastFilePath));
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if` with `while` and display `Intent`:

```
dirpath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
int increase = 0;
file = new File(dirpath+"/NewPDF.pdf");
while(file.exists()) {
    increase++;
    file = new File(dirpath + "/NewPDF" +increase+".pdf");
}
file.createNewFile();

... store data in file here ...

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Time stamp instead of Counter, so that you can create a new file every time.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.US);
    Date timeStamp = new Date();   

     dirpath = 
          android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          // int increase=0;
           file = new File(dirpath+"/NewPDF.pdf");
           if(file.exists()){
               increase++;
               file = new File(dirpath + "/NewPDF" +formatter.format(timeStamp )+".pdf");}
```